How to perform integration test on ASP.NET Core API controller endpoint that requires authentication and validation of antiforgery tokens
Description
I have an ASP.NET Core API controller endpoint that requires:

an authenticated user, and
validation of antiforgery tokens

I want to perform an integration test on this endpoint.
Problem
I am unable to send a request that has both an authenticated user and the necessary antiforgery tokens/cookies and authentication cookies. Therefore, the endpoint continues to return a Bad Request before reaching the handler.
Question
How do you perform an integration test on an endpoint that requires both authentication and validation of antiforgery tokens?
Code
To help walk through this question, I have created a sample application to demonstrate the issue I'm having.
API Controller Endpoints
The sample application has an API controller with four POST endpoints:
1. Unauthenticated (anonymous) endpoint - antiforgery validation NOT required
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("Anonymous/{name}")]
public IActionResult AnonymousPost(string name)
{
    return Ok(name);
}

2. Authenticated endpoint - antiforgery validation NOT required
[HttpPost("Authenticated/{name}")]
public IActionResult AuthenticatedPost(string name)
{
    return Ok(name);
}

3. Unauthenticated (anonymous) endpoint - antiforgery validation required
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost("Anonymous/Antiforgery/{name}")]
public IActionResult AnonymousAntiforgeryPost(string name)
{
    return Ok(name);
}

4. Authenticated endpoint - antiforgery validation required
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost("Authenticated/Antiforgery/{name}")]
public IActionResult AuthenticatedAntiforgeryPost(string name)
{
    return Ok(name);
}

Endpoint #4, which requires an authenticated user as well as validation of antiforgery tokens, is the endpoint I am unable to successfully test.
Authentication
The application uses cookie authentication and requires an authenticated user.
// Add authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
}).AddCookie(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme, options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
    }).AddTwoFactorRememberMeCookie();

// Add authorization
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

The test project configures a test authentication scheme
public static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureTestAuthenticationScheme(this IWebHostBuilder builder, string scheme)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(builder);

    return builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(defaultScheme: "TestScheme")
        .AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, TestAuthHandler>("TestScheme", options => { });
    });
}

Where TestAuthHandler inherits from AuthenticatonHandler and overrides the HandleAuthenticateAsync method.
protected override Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
{
    Claim[] claims = 
    [
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "testuser"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "testuser")
    ];
    ClaimsIdentity identity = new (claims, "Test");
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = new (identity);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new (principal, "TestScheme");

    AuthenticateResult result = AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);

    return Task.FromResult(result);
}

An authenticated client can be created for the test as follows
public HttpClient GetAuthenticatedClient(CookieContainerHandler? cookieHandler = default)
{
    cookieHandler ??= new();

    string testScheme = "TestScheme";

    HttpClient client = WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestAuthenticationScheme(testScheme);
    })
    .CreateDefaultClient(cookieHandler);
    
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(scheme: testScheme);

    return client;
}

Antiforgery
The ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute is used on the two endpoints (#3 & #4) that require antiforgery token validation.
The test project adds an AntiforgeryController to the IWebHostBuilder, which returns a JSON object containing valid antiforgery tokens.
public static IWebHostBuilder ConfigureAntiforgeryTokenResource(this IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(builder);

    return builder.ConfigureTestServices((services) =>
    {
        services.AddControllers()
                .AddApplicationPart(typeof(AntiforgeryTokenController).Assembly);
    });
}

public IActionResult GetAntiforgeryTokens(
    [FromServices] IAntiforgery antiforgery,
    [FromServices] IOptions<AntiforgeryOptions> options)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(antiforgery);
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(options);

    AntiforgeryTokenSet tokens = antiforgery.GetTokens(HttpContext);

    AntiforgeryTokens model = new()
    {
        CookieName = options.Value!.Cookie!.Name!,
        CookieValue = tokens.CookieToken!,
        FormFieldName = options.Value.FormFieldName,
        HeaderName = tokens.HeaderName!,
        RequestToken = tokens.RequestToken!
    };

    return Json(model);
}

The CustomWebApplicationFactory provides a method, GetAntiForgeryTokensAsync, for pinging the AntiforgeryTokenController within a test method.
public async Task<AntiforgeryTokens> GetAntiforgeryTokensAsync(
    Func<HttpClient>? httpClientFactory = null,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    using HttpClient httpClient = httpClientFactory?.Invoke() ?? CreateDefaultClient();

    AntiforgeryTokens? tokens = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<AntiforgeryTokens>(
        AntiforgeryTokenController.GetTokensUri,
        cancellationToken);

    return tokens!;
}

Integration Tests
I am able to successfully test the first three endpoints, however, when I need to test the fourth endpoint, requiring both an authenticated user and antiforgery token validation, a Bad Request is returned.
1. Testing unauthenticated (anonymous) endpoint - antiforgery validation NOT required
public async Task Unauthenticated_request_to_anonymous_endpoint_returns_ok()
{
    // Arrange
    HttpRequestMessage message = new()
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = new Uri("/api/anonymous/testname", UriKind.Relative)
    };

    // Act
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(message);

    // Assert
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

2. Testing authenticated endpoint - antiforgery validation NOT required
public async Task Authenticated_request_to_autheticated_endpoint_returns_ok()
{
    // Arrange
    HttpClient client = _factory.GetAuthenticatedClient();

    HttpRequestMessage message = new()
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = new Uri("/api/authenticated/testname", UriKind.Relative)
    };

    // Act
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);

    // Assert
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}

3. Testing unauthenticated (anonymous) endpoint - antiforgery validation required
public async Task Unauthenticated_request_to_anonymous_antiforgery_endpoint_with_tokens_returns_ok()
{
    // Arrange
    AntiforgeryTokens tokens = await _factory.GetAntiforgeryTokensAsync();

    CookieContainerHandler cookieHandler = new();
    cookieHandler.Container.Add(
        _factory.Server.BaseAddress,
        new Cookie(tokens.CookieName, tokens.CookieValue));

    HttpClient client = _factory.CreateDefaultClient(cookieHandler);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(tokens.HeaderName, tokens.RequestToken);
    
    HttpRequestMessage message = new()
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = new Uri("/api/anonymous/antiforgery/testname", UriKind.Relative)
    };

    // Act
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);

    // Assert
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);   
}

4. Testing authenticated endpoint - antiforgery validation required
I had read the browser automatically extracts any cookie from the server response headers and attaches them to the next request. For the validation to succeed with CSRF, this needs to be simulated. Therefore, this test calls a GetAuthenticationCookies method, which logs into the application and extracts the authentication cookies from the response.
public async Task<List<string>> GetAuthenticationCookies(CookieContainerHandler cookieHandler, AntiforgeryTokens tokens)
{
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource().Token;

    HttpClient client = _factory.CreateDefaultClient(cookieHandler);

    Uri uri = new($"{client.BaseAddress!.AbsoluteUri}login");

    Dictionary<string, string> postData = new()
    {
        { "Input.UserName", "testuser" },
        { "Input.Password", "password" },
        { tokens!.FormFieldName, tokens.RequestToken }
    };

    HttpContent formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(postData);

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, formContent, cancellationToken);

    return response.Headers.GetValues("Set-Cookie").ToList();
}

The test then adds those cookies to the clients request headers in addition to antiforgery tokens.
public async Task Authenticated_request_to_authenticated_antiforgery_endpoint_with_tokens_returns_ok()
{
    // Arrange
    AntiforgeryTokens tokens = await _factory.GetAntiforgeryTokensAsync();

    CookieContainerHandler cookieHandler = new();
    cookieHandler.Container.Add(
        _factory.Server.BaseAddress,
        new Cookie(tokens.CookieName, tokens.CookieValue));

    HttpClient client = _factory.GetAuthenticatedClient(cookieHandler);

    List<string> cookies = await GetAuthenticationCookies(cookieHandler, tokens);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(tokens.HeaderName, tokens.RequestToken);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", cookies);

    HttpRequestMessage message = new()
    {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        RequestUri = new Uri("/api/authenticated/antiforgery/testname", UriKind.Relative)
    };

    // Act
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);

    // Assert
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);   
}

Unfortunately, this test returns a Bad Request, and never reaches the handler.

I don't have an answer, but after authentication the anti-forgery tokens will necessarily have to change.  You'll have a different session. (or should have a different session or you'd be vulnerable to session-fixation attack)  Make sure you generate the token pair AFTER session logged in.

Thanks for the tip. I updated the GetAuthenticationCookies method to get its own antiforgery tokens and in the integration test I get antiforgery tokens again, after logging in. Unfortunately I'm still getting a BadRequest returned.

you might try using antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens instead of GetTokens:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.iantiforgery.getandstoretokens?view=aspnetcore-8.0  Make sure the next request uses those.  Make sure they all use the same session/httpclient.

I see that GetAndStoreTokens stores the antiforgery token in the HttpContext response headers. I am able to add the tokens to the header of the HttpClient already. But I am finding it hard to use the same HttpClient for multiple requests. In some cases, I am using an HttpClient to get information (such as tokens) to create a new HttpClient. I did try changing GetTokens to GetAndStoreTokens. This still ends up returning a bad request...

it'd be worth examining the requests.... but the antiforgery token will be tied to session and form (or previous request/response)  The key is rotated per form/request.  The session is begun with authorization and that is used to derive antiforgery value.  It may be easier to just mock the whole response with form.  (@antiforgery helper will create the token that must be used in the posted form... it calls getandstoretokens)  The cookie doesn't change unless session changes, but the encrypted version (the hidden field in standard posts) will change per form.

Can I ask: Where exactly is Antiforgery declared as a service? is it a part of the code we cannot see in the example?

@PedroCosta - there is no Antiforgery class. However there is an AntiforgeryTokens class, which is basically just a POCO that stores values associated with a given antiforgery token

@browsermator - I'm thinking there may be some issue with getting the authentication cookies. To get the authentication cookies, am logging in to the application at the login endpoint, which uses the ApplicationScheme. When getting an authenticated client for testing, I am using a 'TestScheme'.

you should debug a bit to find which request produces the error exactly, but now that I look at program.cs, it looks like standard antiforgery stuff, so not sure why you use this: client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(tokens.HeaderName, tokens.RequestToken);  The standard antiforgery stuff will use cookie and hidden field (in body of POST)... nothing should be in headers (cookies would be sent but nothing else).  The hidden field should match tokenset created during previous response.  (The only thing that changes is the hidden field... cookie remains the same per session)

just to clarify, if IAntiforgeryOptions have set a headerName, it'll expect the anti-forgery token via header.  Default is to expect that from a hidden field.  HeaderName is for SPA javascript requests.  Do not set options.HeaderName.  "HeaderName The name of the header used by the antiforgery system. If null, the system considers only form data.": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#configure-antiforgery-with-antiforgeryoptions

Not sure those endpoints actually test much at all... are they just getting name from URL?  Not checking POSTed data?

nvm, I get it now, the filters should run before the method is run...  if authentication fails it should return a different error... only lack of proper anti-forgery returns bad request.... (or a malformed request)  Looks like 3 and 4's requests are missing the form data.  So still not sure why 3 works.  But might have to do with GET data being read.  I would change those endpoints to read a form field 'name' instead of getting value via URL (which would typically be a GET, no antiforgery required).  Then make sure to send/POST form data for 3 and 4 tests.... with hidden field for antiforgery.

@browsermator - The sample app represents an API controller, so no form would exist. Microsoft suggests sending the antiforgery tokens in the request header.

The error you're having comes from the fact that in your test the antiforgery token is obtained without being authenticated, so when an authenticated request is made to your API the antiforgery token is not valid.
One way to solve this would be to change your GetAntiforgeryTokensAsync to use an authenticated client based on a parameter :
    public async Task<AntiforgeryTokens> GetAntiforgeryTokensAsync(
        Func<HttpClient>? httpClientFactory = null,
        bool isAuthenticated = false,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        using HttpClient httpClient = isAuthenticated 
            ? this.GetAuthenticatedClient() 
            : (httpClientFactory?.Invoke() ?? CreateDefaultClient());

        AntiforgeryTokens? tokens = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<AntiforgeryTokens>(
            AntiforgeryTokenController.GetTokensUri,
            cancellationToken);

        return tokens!;
    }

You could then change your tests that need authenticated antiforgery tokens to set this parameter
    [Fact]
    public async Task Authenticated_request_to_authenticated_antiforgery_endpoint_with_tokens_returns_ok()
    {
        // Arrange
        List<string> cookies = await GetAuthenticationCookies();

        AntiforgeryTokens tokens = await _factory.GetAntiforgeryTokensAsync(isAuthenticated: true);

        CookieContainerHandler cookieHandler = new();
        cookieHandler.Container.Add(
            _factory.Server.BaseAddress,
            new Cookie(tokens.CookieName, tokens.CookieValue));

        HttpClient client = _factory.GetAuthenticatedClient(cookieHandler);
        
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(tokens.HeaderName, tokens.RequestToken);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", cookies);

        HttpRequestMessage message = new()
        {
            Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("/api/authenticated/antiforgery/testname", UriKind.Relative)
        };
    
        // Act
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(message);

        // Assert
        response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.OK);   
    }


This worked beautifully! I also removed the GetAuthenticatonCookies method - it was unnecessary. The sample application has been updated to reflect working code.
